# Why does a PC case always opens to the left?

Tags: case

The majority of all PC cases are opened on the left side. However, I've seen very few that open on the right side. 
Why is this?

Comment: Because it's a standard.

Comment: Maybe in Israel and in the arabic countries opens at the right. :-)

Comment: @MaXX So its country specific. There isn't a standard, right?

Comment: **BTX** form-factor motherboards (e.g. such as those used by Dell) open on the right (whereas ATX mobo open on the left).  BTX mobos can have an advantage of better cooling: the heatsink of the graphics adapter will face upright in a tower case (for better natural convection) and not interfere with the adjacent expansion card slot.

Comment: standards and their implementation are not a matter of opinion.

Comment: If it is a standard, is it de jure or de facto?

Comment: They are de facto both because AT/ATX have been the most common form-factors in history (by virtue of being paired with the x86 platform), and because it solves a coordination problem, in that motherboard and case manufacturers had to cooperate for a common goal of shipping interoperable parts. the only laws that can really enforce de jure standards on computer engineering are the laws of nature.

Answer (score 8):

Actually many don't. I'm looking at a HP now that opens on the right when facing its front.

The reason is the [AT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_form_factor)/[ATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) [form factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_form_factors#Comparisons) specification, which specifies the size, orrientation, and holes in the motherboard so it can match the mounting screw holes in the case.

Comment: Some older PCs the entire case came off from the top.

Comment: yeah, I used to have a dell 486 "desktop" (non-tower) machine that was proprietary as all get out. thats part of what turned me off to the big names back in the day, when they did everything they could to keep off the shelf replacement parts from fitting.